# Wordpress - How to customize a theme?

Tags: wordpress

I just signed up for wordpress.com, I can see how to edit CSS but I want the header to not be text but rather an image. how do I update the page template on wordpress? on tumblr it's so easy, wordpress is tricky!

Comment: Could you show us a screenshot of what it is precisely you want to change?

Comment: Also, just a thought, but are you aware of the [Wordpress Stack Exchange site](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: Did you say WordPress is tricky?  You can be cancelled for that!  WordPress is amazing and it is agony.

Answer (score 1):

You're very limited with what you can do with css and xhtml on Wordpress.com. You can't write your own page templates or make siginificant changes to .com themes.

What you're probably thinking about is self-hosting Wordpress, and if you do that, you can do whatever you want with themes, css and xhtml. See [Main Page « WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Main_Page) and [Hosting WordPress « WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Hosting_WordPress).

Answer (score 1):

Wordpress.com only let's you edit CSS of their pre-installed themes. Actual theme files cannot be edited, and also you cannot install just any theme you want. You will need to self host your own Wordpress install to customize and add themes in the manner that you are hoping to.

Answer (score 1):

Since you can *only* edit the CSS on Wordpress.com, you might try a background image. You can upload an image into the media section and then, using CSS, format the header area to the height and width that you want and place a background image into the header. And then if you want to get rid of all of the text, you could use something like this on the header to push all of the text off the page:

```
text-align:left;
text-indent:-5000px;
```

Answer (score -1):

please see here.i think it will help you. http://www.wordpressthemebd.blogspot.com/2013/11/wordpress-install-themes.html

Comment: Please, try to read this http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers, to get more understanding how to **not** answer. Namely: "Answers that do not fundamentally answer the question": **barely more than a link to an external site**

Comment: Please, **don't use** [so] to promote your blog. Provide quality content **here**. You can fill your profile and put a link there, and also change your username to *SuperWPBlogger* or something like that ;)